# Is this simple c++ program multithreaded?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio

I am sort of new to C++, but I was wondering if this basic (and possibly sloppy) program is actually running multiple threads at a time or if it its just pooling:

This is a console application running in visual c++ 2015:

```
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>
int temp1 = 0;
int num1 = 0;
int temp2 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
void math1() {
    int running_total = 23;
    for (int i = 0; i < 999999999; i++)
    {
        running_total = 58 * running_total + i;
    }
}
int math2() {

    int running_total = 23;
    for (int i = 0; i < 999999999; i++)
    {
        running_total = 58 * running_total + i;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    unsigned concurentThreadsSupported = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    cout << "Current Number of CPU threads: " << concurentThreadsSupported << endl;
    thread t1(math1);
    thread t2(math2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    cout << "1: " << num1 << endl;
    cout << "2: " << num2 << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I notice when I run the code with `thread t1(math1);thread t2(math2);t1.join();t2.join();`, it uses 25% total of my cpu for 3.5 seconds, but when I use

```
thread t1(math1);
t1.join();
thread t2(math2);
t2.join();
```

it uses ~13% of the CPU for almost 7 seconds.

Is this actually multithreading?

Comment: Well, yes. There are three threads (`main`, `t1`, `t2`). None of them do anything particularly interesting, but it's definitely mutli-threaded...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thread t1(math1); thread t2(math2); t1.join(); t2.join();` waits for `t1` to finish while also running `t2`. The `math1` and `math2` functions do the same thing, so they'll finish approx. at once, which is optimal (it could be just one function as well).

To the numbers you're seeing, you clearly have a CPU with 8 logical cores. The multithreaded version uses two hardware threads (2 / 8) = 25%, while single-threaded just one (1 / 8) = 12,5%. It also runs two times slower, simple.

Comment: (Yes I have 8 cores) So what you are saying is that both threads are running at the same time, but the program is held up until both threads are done?

Comment: @CyberDude Yes, that's what `std::thread:join` does. In this case it doesn't matter, they finish together. In your second example, it's rather clear that the two threads won't be running at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. Also I know its sloppy and I am just experimenting with it, but if I were to write a real program like this (with multiple threads at a time) would it work?

Comment: What can I tell you... if you do everything right, it'll work.